# Ant Design Table VueJS issues

Tags: css, vue.js, ant-design-vue

I am right now trying to have a text area input within my ant design table for VUE. However, it seems that the input box has some problems because the height of the input box will make the fixed column does not align with the current box height.

I'm wondering how I can solve this problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I've attached my screenshot for problems for reference.

I'm trying to set the z-index for that, but it seems that I don't have the correct parent item to be detached from the text area box.

The original table instruction can be found:https://2x.antdv.com/components/table-cn#components-table-demo-fixed-columns-header